# Why EclipseLink maps a NVARCHAR type to an Object?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jpa, eclipselink

I am using the latest version of EclipseLink (2.2.0) with SQL Server 2005.

Generating the classes, the type NVARCHAR is mapped to type Object in the classes.

I suppose it should map to type String.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

How are you generating the classes?  Are you using Eclipse Dali?

I would just change the generate code to String.  Perhaps report a bug with the IDE you are using.  EclipseLink itself, does not generate classes.